# what is the usage of cascade=evict in hibernate hbm file

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Can some one explain me what is the usage of `cascade = "evict"` in a hibernate mapping file.

Mapping file excerpt:

```
<set name="details" cascade="evict">
  <key column="detailid"></key>
  <one-to-many class="com.intialize.example.Details"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evict is the same as DETACH and is deprecated.

See the API doc
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html#EVICT

And here an excellent article about cascade types:
https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

From the docs

5.12. Evicting entities
When the flush() method is called, the state of the entity is synchronized with the database. If you do not want this synchronization to occur, or if you are processing a huge number of objects and need to manage memory efficiently, the evict() method can be used to remove the object and its collections from the first-level cache.

Example 329. Detaching an entity from the EntityManager

```
for(Person person : entityManager.createQuery("select p from Person p", Person.class)
        .getResultList()) {
    dtos.add(toDTO(person));
    entityManager.detach( person );
}
```

Example 330. Evicting an entity from the Hibernate Session

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
for(Person person : (List<Person>) session.createQuery("select p from Person p").list()) {
    dtos.add(toDTO(person));
    session.evict( person );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got your point,even though we are calling evict() method explicitly, why we are again declaring cascade="evict" in hibernate mapping file

Comment: cascade means if you call evict on the parent object it will cascade to its children

Comment: Marking comments and/or answers as useful or correct would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

From the Hibernate Javadocs:

> This operation [[`evict()`]](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object)) cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with `cascade="evict"`.

Answer (score 0):

With evict you tell hibernate to remove an entity from the first-level cache context and like all the other operations (persist, update, remove, etc...) can be cascaded to all the child of a particular relationship...

So when you call evict on the entity where this relation is defined

```
<set name="details" cascade="evict">
  <key column="detailid"></key>
  <one-to-many class="com.intialize.example.Details"/>
</set>
```

hibernate is going to evict all the Details associated too